# How to start Application in Background in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to run the application in background.I tried many aspects but my bad luck.
below is my code where I used the Process Method to run in background.

```
private bool launchdoors(string username, string password, string location)

{  
proc = Process.Start("chrome.exe", "-u " + username + " -P " + password + " -
W" + "-d" + location);
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;  
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStayle.Hidden;  
return true;

}
```

Comment: Some applications dont work in a manner that makes this possible - in that they spawn other copies of themselves irrelevant of your desires

Comment: There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31627801/1997232) with `Chrome` and `background`. Can you explain what you want and what happens instead? As well as what are others *"many aspects"* you have tried (maybe you did something wrong, but the idea is correct)?

Comment: I want to starts doors clients process in background,so that GUI will not be visible.