# The console turns off when I run it through Process.Start c#

Tags: c#

because of what the console can be turned off?

```
                Process process;
                process = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Bapcuk\source\repos\Server\Server\bin\Debug\Servers\MyServer\start.bat");
                process.WaitForExit();
                break;
```

code in .bat file - `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar PAUSE`

Comment: Do you want to hide console window, or to redirect console output?

Comment: `process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;` or `process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I start a process in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627801/how-can-i-start-a-process-in-the-background)

Comment: I want it not to close at startup