# Is there a way to make a form stay behind another window?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm Currently Developing a Windows Server Core Shell/Windows Shell Replacement that's CPU and RAM Efficient.

But it keeps getting in the way if I click on the Desktop.

Is there any way of letting it stay on the desktop/behind all other windows?

It Shouldn't take too much CPU and Ram.

Comment: [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Comment: Really? You can write a full-featured windows shell replacement in C# that's more CPU and RAM efficient than the Microsoft implementation? If it is really a shell, you can let start your application instead of explorer.exe and gain full control: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms838576(v=winembedded.5)

Comment: @Oliver Yes i can (Currently only 16 MB RAM). i will release it on GitHub when finished.

Answer (score 0):

Cant comment yet, so here is something ive found:
[Setting a Windows form to be bottommost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027536/setting-a-windows-form-to-be-bottommost)
so you only have to add this to your class / Form

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices;DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
```

and then on the Form.Activate and the Form.Load event you have to run the declared method like this:

```
SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```

Code from [*Richard Ev*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39709/richard-ev)