# Change system z-order of BrowserWindow in electron, possible?

Tags: javascript, desktop-application, electron

I need to control main window z-order so to say. Always on top is not my case. I want to put my window behind all others and above desktop. Is it possible? Is there analogue to C++ SetWindowPos function? Or maybe some workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not something you can accomplish with [parent/child windows](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#parent-and-child-windows) then you could call `SetWindowPos()` via [`node-ffi`](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) (or write a native Node module/addon). To get the `HWND` for a `BrowserWindow` call [`getNativeWindowHandle()`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#wingetnativewindowhandle). I have no idea how you'd do this natively on macOS or Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've really helped.

Answer (score 9):

First you should send the window to the back/bottom of the z-index stack, then disable z-index changing for the window.

I tried getting this working in my project, and eventually succeeded, as shown below.

However, note that some of my code comments might not be accurate. I don't understand node-ffi very well, and only got it working through trial and error; my code comments are just my attempt at trying to "make sense" of the behavior I observed.

```
import ffi from "ffi";
import ref from "ref";
import Struct from "ref-struct";

const HWND_BOTTOM = 1;
export let SetWindowPos_Flags = {
    NOSIZE: 0x0001,
    NOMOVE: 0x0002,
    NOACTIVATE: 0x0010,
}

export var user32 = new ffi.Library("user32", {
    // return, handle, handleInsertAfter, x, y, cx, cy, flags
    SetWindowPos: ["bool", ["int32", "int32", "int32", "int32", "int32", "int32", "uint32"]],
});

export function SendWindowToBack(handle: number) {
    user32.SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SetWindowPos_Flags.NOMOVE | SetWindowPos_Flags.NOSIZE | SetWindowPos_Flags.NOACTIVATE);
}

export const WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046;
export const SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
let WINDOWPOS = Struct({
    hwndInsertAfter: ffi.types.int32,
    hwnd: ffi.types.int32,
    x: ffi.types.int32,
    y: ffi.types.int32,
    cx: ffi.types.int32,
    cy: ffi.types.int32,
    flags: ffi.types.uint32,
});
export function AddHook(window: Electron.BrowserWindow, disableZIndexChanging = false) {
    window.hookWindowMessage(WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, (wParam: Buffer, lParam: Buffer)=> {
        // The "lParam" buffer holds the address to a place in unmanaged memory, which itself holds the address to the actual (unmanaged) struct-data.
        // Thus: js-pseudo-pointer (8-bytes; the lParam Buffer) -> c-pointer (8-bytes, unmanaged) -> struct-data (28-bytes, unmanaged)
        // However, the lParam buffer does not realize it is/could-be a "pseudo-pointer" -- all it knows is that it's holding some random numbers.
        // To access the unmanaged struct-data, we have to tell the js-side that the contents of lParam are actually the address explained above.
        // Then we'll be able to use the Buffer.deref() function to correctly obtain the final struct-data.

        // To do this, we:
        // 1) Create a new js-pseudo-pointer (using the modified Buffer class), whose contents/what-it-points-to is marked as of type "pointer to a pointer" (ie. the c-pointer entry above)
        let lParam2 = Buffer.alloc(8);
        lParam2["type"] = ref.refType(WINDOWPOS);

        // 2) Fill the js-pseudo-pointer with the actual address to that c-pointer (just copy this address from the unmarked lParam Buffer)
        lParam.copy(lParam2);

        // 3) Dereference our js-pseudo-pointer, retrieving the actual struct-data bytes
        let actualStructDataBuffer = lParam2["deref"]() as Buffer;

        // 4) Convert the struct-data bytes into a regular JavaScript object
        let windowPos = actualStructDataBuffer["deref"]() as {hwndInsertAfter: number, hwnd: number, x: number, y: number, cx: number, cy: number, flags: number};

        // 5) Modify the 7th integer (the flags field) in the (unmanaged) struct-data, to include the new SWP_NOZORDER flag
        if (disableZIndexChanging) {
            //lParam.flags |= SWP_NOZORDER;
            let newFlags = windowPos.flags | SWP_NOZORDER;
            actualStructDataBuffer.writeUInt32LE(newFlags, 6);
        }
    });
}

// This is the function you actually call from the rest of your program.
export function SendElectronWindowToBackAndKeepItThere(window: Electron.BrowserWindow) {
    let handleAsBuffer = window.getNativeWindowHandle();
    let handleAsNumber = ref.types.int64.get(handleAsBuffer, 0);
    SendWindowToBack(handleAsNumber);
    AddHook(window, true);
}
```

Comment: This is amazing thank you for sharing :)
For anyone that might try to use this with the latest electron version (I'm on 8.0.0) you need to use `ffi-napi`, `ref-napi`, `ref-struct-napi` that support nodejs 12 (which latest electron versions use).

Comment: @giotiskl Yeah, the `ffi` (and such) repos seem to have been abandoned by the author for the last couple years (which is odd since he's still active on Github!); `ffi-napi` has also worked well for me as a replacement.

Comment: I've gotten this code to work by importing the 'napi' versions like giotiskl mentioned above. Had some trouble setting it up in a vue project and used https://juejin.cn/post/6854573212341108749 to fix it. I reverted to node 12 instead of node 15 (not sure if that fixed something or did it wrong multiple times in a row before).

@Venryx can this code be copy-pasted to an open source project and if so, how should it be licensed?

Comment: @Flaff Do whatever you want with the code -- consider the code block public domain (no attribution required). If you need a specific license, then you can also consider it MIT licensed. (the standard license I specify on GitHub)

Comment: @Venryx This [Link](https://gist.github.com/lowfront/528a658d25e4357c07c8ea4f1b2cb46c) is an example of running on the Node.js 14 version and Electron 14 version. I made it by referring to your code. Thank you.

Comment: This code was amazingly helpful in creating my application! Thanks so much for this snippet @Venryx !

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`.blur()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winblur) on the window. It will make it go below other windows.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! Not very well documented what this does. `BrowserWindow.blur()` is needed to maintain good UX in a lot of cases when launching native OS windows or other programs which for some reason open behind the Electron app window, for example when using `showItemInFolder()`.