# How to get window z-index,z-order or order of window in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I need to check if a window is on top or bottom of other windows including other processes than Electron.

for example: I have

- "A" Electron window
- "B" Electron window
- "C" Other process window

User click on "A" and immediately click on "C" and then click on "B"
which is where I want to check if "A" is on top of other windows or not.

Are there any method or workaround to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your goal yet - do you want to check wether your window is focused?

Comment: @Rhayene no, I want to get the z-index, z-order or order of "A" window after the user clicked on "C"  and then "B".

Comment: I'm sorry if my previous comment was confusing - I wanted to understand what you want to use the z-index for, to see if blur or a modal window or something else would achive what you want.

Comment: @Rhayene I want to use z-index or z-order to find out if window "A" is under window "C" or not.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but this may be interesting: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wingetnativewindowhandle

Comment: Thanks,@Rhayene, you just saved me with that API. Looks like I will have to implement some C++ addons to access native API and use HWND got from the API.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39435066/4945892