# What is the equivalent of C#'s Marshal.PtrToStructure and StructureToPtr in node-ffi?

Tags: c#, marshalling, ffi, node-ffi

The C# functions are described below.

Marshal.PtrToStructure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure

> Marshals data from an unmanaged block of memory to a managed object.
>
> Parameters
>   ptr (IntPtr): A pointer to an unmanaged block of memory.
>
> structure (Object): The object to which the data is to be copied. This must be an instance of a formatted class.

Marshal.StructureToPtr: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr

> Marshals data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
>
> Parameters
>   structure (Object): A managed object that holds the data to be marshaled. This object must be a structure or an instance of a formatted class.
>
> ptr (IntPtr): A pointer to an unmanaged block of memory, which must be allocated before this method is called.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know of a general-purpose function that's as easy to use as `Marshal.PtrToStructure/StructureToPtr`, I did figure out a lower-level way of accomplishing the same sort of thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473299/2441655

Summary: Find/create a node-ffi Buffer that directly points to the struct-data in unmanaged memory, then:

- To read: Set the Buffer's `type` field appropriately, then call `deref()`.
- To write: Call `buffer.writeUInt32LE`, with the offset of the given field supplied.